# How do I insert rows into a spatial table within a geopackage file via a SQL INSERT statement?

Tags: sqlite, geopackage

I am attempting to insert rows into a spatial table within a geopackage file using DBeaver 5.1.1.

I receive an error from the triggers, referencing functions that don't exist: `ST_IsEmpty`.  Do I need to load these functions via a similar means to the spatialite `load_extension`? And does a library extension exist for geopackages?

```
SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: ST_IsEmpty)
  [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: ST_IsEmpty)
  [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: ST_IsEmpty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of answered my own question in the question.  I issued a
`SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite.dll');` 
statement (files are already in my path).  And I was able insert my rows.  While it works, there may be a more correct way to do it? Like using a geopackage specific extension?

Also for DBeaver, I had to enable_load_extension on the driver properties.
[image]

Comment: There is no official extension for delivering the handful of functions defined in gpkg standard. With SpatiaLite they come in a quite heavy package. Luciad has a smaller library https://bitbucket.org/luciad/libgpkg, or then you can use GDAL or perhaps GeoTools.

Comment: GDAL implements the functions probably in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/sqlite/ogrsqlitesqlfunctions.cpp.

Comment: Just tried the Luciad `gpkg.dll`, works great!